# Why does my brush look different than it's supposed to?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, brush, texture

This is the video from which I downloaded the brush: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mdLr3CA0z-k
And it was supposed to look like this

[image: Notice the texture!]

but it looks like this (I did not change the brush and I am using PS 2020), just plain brush with solid color and no texture.

[image]

What's wrong here?

I am not using any graphics tablet. If this is the problem then how can I do this texture with a mouse(I need that texture look)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Graphic tablets allow you to use different expressions for more control over the brush stroke: all of them support pen pressure, some allow to use pen tilt, pen rotation, etc. The preview you see on your first image shows how the brush stroke would look like with the expressions enabled: it's set to `Pen Pressure` for opacity, flow and diameter. There's also a `Dual Brush` setting that controls a texture — also with the pen pressure.

With a mouse you don't have a way to control pressure sensitivity so you can't really replicate the same behaviour. What you could try is to set brush `Flow` setting to something low like 5-10%. You won't get a smooth transition between the settings but you'll get a bit of a texture:

[image]

However to have a full control you should consider getting a graphic tablet.